# Window is bigger than my workspace

Tags: workspaces

I'm running Linux with Ubuntu in VB. I have it installed and all is working well except for one thing that I can figure out how to fix. When I click on settings and go into any of the options there, my settings window is bigger than my screen and I can't see the bottom of it. Entering fullscreen does not help as the settings window simply becomes bigger along with it. Hopefully that makes sense.

If not I can upload a screen shot or try and provide more detail. Thank you for any help you can provide. If this questions has already been asked before, please accept my apologies. 
[image]

Comment: post screenshot ?

Comment: I guess to simplify it I want to know how to scale the window so that it fits within the workspace. I know I can drag and scale the window at the corners, but i can't scale it from the top corners which are the only ones I can access.

Comment: Press Alt and drag the window works.  (The question was recently asked, but I can't find it right now).

Comment: that does work, but I think part of the problem is that guest additions did not install properly. [screenshot](http://imgur.com/OvQZWw1)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Guest Additions? Guest additions change resolution of virtual OS dynamically. Maybe it would help.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Comment: hey i did, but it didn't seem to change anything. its not a huge deal as holding Alt to drag the window does work, just would be nice to have the window scaled to the proper size.

Comment: I think something went wrong though when trying to install it.
http://imgur.com/OvQZWw1

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. I upgraded virtual box and reinstalled guest additions. After a restart all was working. Not sure what exactly fixed it but we're good now! Thanks!